# Z-indexing issues

Tags: html, css

Real simple problem I have here... Been trying to get the a sub-menu of an `<li>`'s background to show up behind the `<li>` but can't seem to figure out.

I tried a few things, and I know I had it the other day but for some reason today I just can't figure it out.

**Here's the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/F8BeF/
Trying to get the red background to show up behind the button.

**Here's the Code:**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="epsonNav">
    <li id="receipt"><a href="../epson/home.aspx"><span id="receiptDropDown" class="arrows"></span> </a>
           <ul id="receiptDropMenu">
                        <li>TM-T88V</li>
           </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.epsonNav{position: relative; z-index:10}
.epsonNav li{margin-top: 5px; width: 154px; list-style: none;}
.epsonNav a{height: 43px; display: block;}

#receipt{background:url('https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png') -41px -373px;}
#receipt a:hover{background:url('https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png') -228px -373px;}
#receiptDropDown {display:block; height: 40px; width: 35px; left: 117px; position: absolute;}
#receiptDropMenu {position: relative; z-index: 1; background: red; padding-top:10px; margin-top: -10px;}
```

Comment: do you want a red background for both the button and the text `TM-T88V` or just for the button?

Comment: To get the red background below your current image just set the z-index of `#receiptDropMenu` to -1: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/F8BeF/1/

Comment: @koala_dev post this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is have the red background appear behind your current image then set the `z-index` of the `#receiptDropMenu` to `-1` instead of `1`.

See **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/F8BeF/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea:

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="top-level">
        <li><a href="#"></a>
            <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.top-level {background:#FFFFFF;}
ul.top-level li {
 background:url('https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png') -41px -373px;
    width: 154px;
}
#nav ul.sub-level {border:1px solid yellow;}
#nav a {
 color: #000000;
 cursor: pointer;
 display:block;
 height:25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 text-indent: 10px;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:100%;
}
#nav a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav li:hover {
 position: relative;
}
ul.sub-level {
    display: none;  
}
li:hover .sub-level {
    background: #999;
    border: #fff solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
    top: 5px;
}
ul.sub-level li {
    border: none;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    background: red;
}

#nav .sub-level {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `background:red` for `receipt` instead of `receiptDropMenu`. Hence your code should be as follows

### HTML

```
<ul class="epsonNav">
        <li id="receipt"><a href="../epson/home.aspx"><span id="receiptDropDown" class="arrows"></span> </a>
               <ul id="receiptDropMenu">
                            <li>TM-T88V</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.epsonNav{position: relative; z-index:10}
.epsonNav li{margin-top: 5px; width: 154px; list-style: none;}
.epsonNav a{height: 43px; display: block;}

#receipt{background:url('https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png') -41px -373px; background: red;}
#receipt a:hover{background:url('https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png') -228px -373px;}
#receiptDropDown {display:block; height: 40px; width: 35px; left: 117px; position: absolute;}
#receiptDropMenu {position: relative; z-index: 1; padding-top:10px; margin-top: -10px;}
```

### O/P

**when you hover over the area above the text `TM-T88V` the button will appear.**

Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F8BeF/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer to your question dear friend: "http://jsfiddle.net/F8BeF/5/"

HTML:

```
<ul class="epsonNav">
    <li ><a href="../epson/home.aspx" id="receipt"><span id="receiptDropDown" class="arrows"></span> </a>
           <ul id="receiptDropMenu">
                        <li>TM-T88V</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.epsonNav{position: relative; z-index:10}
.epsonNav li{margin-top: 5px; width: 154px; list-style: none;}
.epsonNav a{height: 43px; display: block;}
#receipt{background:url('https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png') -41px -373px; position:relative; z-index:2}
#receipt a:hover{background:url('https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png') -228px -373px;}
#receiptDropDown {display:block; height: 40px; width: 35px; left: 117px; position: absolute;}
#receiptDropMenu {position: relative; z-index: 1; background: red; padding-top:10px; margin-top: -30px;}
```